# Remove the cycles

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, matrix, linear-algebra

I need to get rid of loops in my Matlab code. During this procedure, i encountered the following problem. Here is the part of the code

```
Nx=11; Ny=11; 
A=rand(Ny,Nx);
A1=A;
 
       for j=2:Ny-1      
       for i=2:Nx-1
          A(j,i)=A(j,i-1);
       end;
       end;
 
A1(2:Ny-1,2:Nx-1)=A1(2:Ny-1,1:Nx-2);
 
A2=A-A1;
```

I get that `A` is not equal to `A1`. The situation is the same with the `j-1` index on the right side. However, if we take the index `i + 1` or `j + 1`, then everything works fine.

Comment: “I need to get rid of loops in my Matlab code.” Why? Is this a “common sense knowledge that loops are slow” thing? Or did you determine with the profiler that this particular loop is a bottleneck in your code? Loops in MATLAB haven’t been slow for many, many years. Sure, vectorized code is sometimes still faster, but the gains are marginal. You need to profile your code before you decide which bit of code to put time and effort in to speed up.

Comment: I need to do this procedure since i use parallel GPU computing. CPU code works fine with the loops in terms of speed with the moderate grid size. On the contrary, the code should be vectorized for GPU computing to gain impressive speedup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is relatively simple: you are shifting the columns of `A1` to the right all at once (copying over column 1 into 2 and discarding column `Nx-1` in the process), whereas your `for` loop shifts the columns of `A` to the right one at a time, left to right. This means that first you overwrite column 2 with the contents of column 1, then 3 with 2, and so on, so that you finally end up with `Nx-1` copies of the first column. (When I speak of copying/moving/discarding columns, I mean their values from row `2` to row `Ny-1`.)

As you have noticed, if you modify your loop to shift columns to the left, i.e.

```
for j=2:Ny-1
  for i=2:Nx-1
    A(j,i)=A(j,i+1);
%...
```

then this issue does not happen, since you have a chance to read the original contents of any given column and save them elsewhere before overwriting them with new values.

All of the above results apply when the `for` loop iterates over columns from left to right. If you reverse the direction of iteration, i.e.

```
%...
  for i=Nx-1:-1:2
    A(j,i)=%...
```

then right-shifting columns works as intended, while shifting them to the left produces bogus results.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise explanation!